# Best method for finding the order of an intersection of groups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $H,K$ be proper subgroups of a group $G$. If $|K|=39$ and $|H|=65$, what are the possible orders of $K\cap H$? Enter your answer as a comma separated list.

**My answer: 13,1**

**Motivation:**

Let $Q=K\cap H$; by Lagrange's Theorem, $Q\over39$ and $Q\over65$, so this effectively becomes a basic number theory question; I need to find all common divisors of 39 and 65.

Thus, I first find the $gcd(39,65)=13$, since all common divisors are also divisors of the $gcd$.
(how do I prove this? I tried.) Since 13 is prime, the only possible orders of $Q$ are 13 and 1.

Have I done this question correctly / is there a better way? I have not taken a formal number theory course yet, so I am quite weak at it.

Comment: You don't need any formal number theory course!

Comment: You are right. $H\cap K \le H $and $H\cap K \le K$.By Lagrange's theorem $|H\cap K| $ divides both $|H|$ and $|K|$ and $|H\cap K|\mid \gcd(|H|, |K|) $

Comment: $\frac{Q}{39}$ is nonsensical notation. $Q$ is a group, and you don't do fractions of groups divided by numbers.If you mean "the order if $Q$ divides $39$", then the proper notation is $|Q|$ for "the order of $Q$". It would be "$|Q|\mid 39$."

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer, you will have to give a specific example of $G,H,K$ for $|Q|=13$, as well as for $|Q|=1$.

That shouldn't be hard, but if you want a hint, see the next lines of this answer.

Hint:

$|Q|=13$: a cyclic group of order $3\times5\times13$

$|Q|=1$: a direct product of $H$ and $K$